# C++ program core dump due to new a huge size of memory by <string>

Tags: string, malloc

My program reported a core dump back trace as following:

```
0000000011deaae2     MEMalloc_fail     110      /home/jenkins/workspace/shared/memory/MEMlocal.c
00000000121b3026     MEMalloc              3134 (discriminator 1)      tor 1)
00000000121bec8f     operator new          34      /home/jenkins/workspace/memory/MEMnew_del.cpp
0000000010027e15     void std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_construct<char*>   219      /usr/include/c++/8/bits/basic_string.tcc
00007fa34d58f7c7     ??
```

The operator new is hooked and managed by our own code. The MEMlocal.c source code also has following error log. It complains a very big size of memory is requested, size=8385546811006266694, but we don't know how to debug the root cause.

```
Err (MEMlocal.c 110
Assert: BADPARAM from MEMalloc_fail()
Function Trace:
0000000011deaae2 00000000121b3026 00000000121bec8f 0000000010027e15
00007fa34d58f7c7
Register Dump:
DI  =  00007fa3178e5920   SI  =  00007fa30cee96d0
DX  =  0000000000000080   CX  =  00007fa300000000
User String:
[line=2043] Parameters: addr_ptr=0x7fa30ceea158 size=8385546811006266694 
Absolute allocation size limit for this pool=28505545 blocks.
Usage=0xc6172e/0x1b2f5c9 [45.542233%]
```

Thanks for any clue for the next step debug.